# Winding number of a path

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $c:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2- \{0\}$ be a closed path with winding number $k$. Determine the winding number of the following paths $\tilde{c}:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2- \{0\}$:

1. $\tilde{c}=\rho(t)c(t)$, where $\rho:[0,1]\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is a function satisfying $\rho(0)=\rho(1)$.
2. $\tilde{c}=\left\|c(t)\right\|^{-1}c(t)$.

In the firt one I think that is

\begin{align*}
\omega(\rho c,0)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\rho c}\alpha_0\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{[0,1]}(\rho c)^*\alpha_0\\
&=\omega(\rho,0)+\omega(c,0)\\\
&=k
\end{align*}

Where $\alpha_0=\frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}$ and $*$ represents the pullback.

I'm not sure if it's fine and the second one I don't have idea.

Answer (score 0):

The second path is just the path $c$ projected onto the standard unit circle sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$.  I don't know enough of your notation to be able to figure out how you're doing your integral, but it definitely follows from your first calculation (think about what $\rho$ should be in this case).